# Creating Non-Lambda Proxy AWS API Gateway in CodePipeline

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-codepipeline, aws-cloudformation

Created the Lambda Function (POST) and corresponding API Gateway using Code Pipeline. By default the API Gateway got created with lambda Proxy type integration. What parameters in SAM I should give that my API Gateway gets created with Non Lambda Proxy type Integration.

Below is my SAM Template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09' Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-  31 Description: Outputs the time Resources: TimeFunction: Type: AWS::Serverless::Function Properties: Handler: index.handler Runtime: nodejs6.10 CodeUri: ./ Events: MyTimeApi: Type: Api Properties: Path: /TimeResource Method: GET CalculatorFunction: Type: AWS::Serverless::Function Properties: Handler: calc.calculator Runtime: nodejs6.10 CodeUri: ./ Events: MyCalculatorApi: Type: Api Properties: Path: /Calculator Method: POST
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define any Swagger definition you want if you use the `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource. There are examples of swagger definitions in our developer guide and you can also export your existing API to swagger from the Stages page. In this case, the `type` field on the `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` structure in Swagger should be `aws` rather than `aws_proxy`.

There is no way to set this field when you are setting the API Event type inline on the Lambda function in SAM.

Comment: So does it make sense if in my SAM I create one Lambda Function Resource and its corresponding API Resource just after that instead of setting the API Event type inline on the Lambda function. And when I will call my API from outside world it will eventually call the Lambda defined in API Resource.